# indexOf of specific words in a string

Tags: java, string, indexof

I have a string given below

```
ABC+LONDONABC+1200+XX+PP:200'VAN+200+HH:LONDON?'OCP+FFLOAN'TAN+200+HOLANDOCP+NORWAY:1200+LL'OCP+200+500'
```

If I split this string on the basis of string separator, four string would come out like this

```
1) ABC+LONDONABC+1200+XX+PP:200'
2) VAN+200+HH:LONDON?'OCP+FFLOAN'
3) TAN+200+HOLANDOCP+NORWAY:1200+LL'
4) OCP+200+500'
```

This string always comes in single line and here the fact is the whole string is a combination of multiple strings. So single quote is an string separator.

Second, single quote can also come in between a substring as well like below in LONDON?'OCP  So ? is an release character.

```
VAN+200+HH:LONDON?'OCP+FFLOAN'
```

I want to deal whole string in a single line only.

My requirement is to extract substrings which starts from ABC and OCP. ABC would be always first substring in a String and OCP would be last always.

I want two string out of this whole string

```
1) ABC+LONDONABC+1200+XX+PP:200'
2) OCP+200+500'
```

When I extract String starting from ABC using index of with index overloading to get an first occurrence of single quote, Its coming fine.

But when I try to extract OCP's string, It comes fine if whole string doesnt have any other OCP or OCP+ or 'OCP+ containing words. But if comes like coming into above mentioned string...

For example, check these two substrings

```
TAN+200+HOLANDOCP+NORWAY:1200+LL'
VAN+200+HH:LONDON?'OCP+FFLOAN'
```

In First OCP is coming in HOLANDOCP+. This dont allow me to take a last substring starting from OCP+ to end of the whole string.

IN second, OCP is coming into LONDON?'OCP with substring separator.

How can I extract last substring from whole string starting OCP to end of the string if I receive other OCPs like I've mentioned in above examples ..?

Comment: What's a *release character*? Did you mean *escape character* by any chance?

Comment: If you would tell us what your search and research has brought up and in what way it was insufficient, there will be a much greater chance that we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @domdom, Ole V.V I have updated my question And Yes domdom its an escape character..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have that situation in which the single quote always surrounds the last `OCP` phrase, you can just `split` by `'`, and get the last element in the returned array

```
String fullStr = "ABC+LONDONABC+1200+XX+PP:200'VAN+200+HH:LONDON?'OCP+FFLOAN'TAN+200+HOLANDOCP+NORWAY:1200+LL'OCP+200+500'";

String[] substrArr = fullStr.split("'");
String substr = substrArr[substrArr.length - 1];
System.out.println(substr); // will output OCP+200+500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Scanner. First you said that the substrings are separated by ', so you can tokenize the string into strings using that and then retain the first and the last string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input = "ABC+LONDONABC+1200+XX+PP:200'VAN+200+HH:LONDON?'OCP+FFLOAN'TAN+200+HOLANDOCP+NORWAY:1200+LL'OCP+200+500'";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
    scanner.useDelimiter("'");
    String first = "";
    if (scanner.hasNext()) first = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(first);
    String last = "";
    while (scanner.hasNext())
      last = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(last);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want. From your question I also understand that maybe the string starting with ABC is not always first, but if this is the case then you can iterate over each substring and check if it contains "ABC" or "OCP".

Answer (score 0):

Regex is powerful at handling this type of thing. Here's one possible solution:

```
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    String test = "ABC+LONDONABC+1200+XX+PP:200'VAN+200+HH:LONDON?'OCP+FFLOAN'TAN+200+HOLANDOCP+NORWAY:1200+LL'OCP+200+500'";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\A|[^\\?]')(((ABC|OCP).*?)(\\z|[^\\?]'))").matcher(test);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matches.add(matcher.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println(matches);
```

Output:

```
[ABC+LONDONABC+1200+XX+PP:200', OCP+200+500']
```

The regex has three parts:

1. This `(\\A|[^\\?]')` says either the beginning of the input or a ' that is not preceded by a ?.
2. The middle part `((ABC|OCP).*?)` is to find the parts between the ' that begins with either ABC or OCP.
3. The last part `(\\z|[^\\?]')` is to find either the end of input or a ' not preceded by a ?.

There is an extra set of parentheses around the middle and end so it will include the ending ' like you specified in your desired output. If you don't want the ' at the end, you could remove those parentheses.

Comment: could you please explain your regex ..?

Comment: @LearnJava I've edited the answer to add an explanation of the regex.